# How to display a queue in C with Linked list

Tags: c, queue

I want to display the current state of a queue with linked list implementation, `printqueue` tries to do this.

The `printqueue` as i said above tries to do this ,but i can't edit the inside code of it or any function or struct. So the only solution that i can have, is to change the way that i am calling it (with different init of parametes). When i am running this code with empty queue i am taking seg fault or with non-empty i am taking nothing.

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define PLATE_LENGTH 9

struct node
{
    char data[PLATE_LENGTH];
    struct node *next;
};
typedef struct node *PTR;

void enqueue(char obj[],PTR *pf,PTR *pr)
{
    PTR newnode;
    newnode=(PTR*)malloc(sizeof(PTR)); 
    assert(newnode!=NULL);
    strcpy(newnode->data,obj);
    newnode->next=NULL;
    if((*pf)==NULL)
    {
        *pf=newnode;
        *pr=newnode;
    }
    else
    {
        (*pr)->next=newnode;
        *pr=newnode;
    }

    printf("Insertion Completed!\n");

}


void dequeue(PTR *pf,PTR *pr)
{
    PTR p;
    if((*pf)==NULL)
        printf("\nQueue empty. No elements to delete.\n");
    else
    {
        p=*pf;
        *pf=(*pf)->next;
        if((*pf)==NULL) *pr=*pf;
        printf("%s has been deleted...\n",p->data);
        free(p);
    }
}

void printqueue(PTR p,PTR pr)
{

    while(p!=NULL)
    {
        printf("\n\t\t%s",p->data);
        p=p->next;
    }
}


int edisplay_menu()
{
    int input=0;
    printf("MENU\n======\n1.Car Arrival\n2.Car Departure\n3.Queue State\n0.Exit\n");
    printf("Choice?");
    scanf("%d",&input);
    return input;

}


PTR *pf=NULL,*pr=NULL;


int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{
    int input=1;
    char *plate=(char*) malloc(PLATE_LENGTH*sizeof(char));
    PTR front,rear;

    if (plate==NULL)
    {
         printf("Out of memory!\n");
         return (1);
    }

   input=edisplay_menu();
   while(input!=0)
   {
        if(input==1) //in case of car arrival
        {
            printf("Give the car's plate:");
            scanf("%s",plate);
            enqueue(plate,&pf,&pr);  //insert car plate to queue
        }
        if(input==2) //in case of departure
        {
            dequeue(&pf,&pr); //delete car plate from queue
        }
        if(input==3)
        {
         front=*pf;
         printqueue(front,rear); //display all car plates in queue
        }
        if(input==0)
        {
            printf("Bye!!!");
            exit(1);
        }

   input=edisplay_menu();

   }

    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are confused about the variables to use.

You have the global variables:

```
PTR *pf=NULL,*pr=NULL;
```

and inside `main`you have:

```
PTR front,rear;
```

Then you use `pf` and `pr` for the enqueing and `front`and `rear` for printing.

Solution: Get rid of the global variables (notice that currently they also have wrong type)

BTW: `front` and `rear` are uninitialized when you call the print function which may cause crashes.

Comment: You mean to put the global vars , inside of main or delete it them?

Comment: @JHk1821 I mean: **delete the global variables** They are not needed as you pass the pointers as function parameters. And remember to initialize front and rear in main

Comment: but both in ```enqueue```  & in ```dequeue``` i am using ```pf``` and ```pr``` , ```front``` and ```rear``` its just type of PTR the others is pointers of struct PTR

Comment: @JHk1821 .. and once the global variables are deleted, you'll need to fix your main so that is use `front` and `rear` in all function calls.

Comment: @JHk1821 No.... front and rear are the correct type. The call is to be: `enqueue(plate,&front,&rear);` It is the `&` that takes the address so that the function receives a `PTR*`

Comment: I'm confused by the fact that `enqueue` only appears allocates enough space for a `struct node *` (a `PTR`), not a `struct node`. Surely `newnode=(PTR*)malloc(sizeof(PTR));` should be `newnode=(PTR)malloc(sizeof(*newnode));`?

Comment: @IanAbbott Nice catch - I didn't notice that. The correct allocation would be: `newnode=malloc(sizeof *newnode);` This is a good example of "don't typedef pointers" ;-)